# Disable selection changing in Word 2000

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2000

I am using Word 2000 and am struggling to select particular groups of words. It seems that if I select *most* of a paragraph, then word thinks its doing me a favour by changing my selection to *all* of the paragraph. Similarly, if I select some of the text in a single table cell, word often highlights the entire cell, or even the entire row! Can I disable this feature?

**EDIT:** I should have mentioned that I have been viewing the document using the outline view. I have noticed that the behaviour is different in the normal view. The problems appear far less in normal mode, but I prefer to edit using outlines.

**EDIT:** After some more experimentation, the problem can be boiled down to the following. In outline view mode, I can not highlight any piece of text in a table cell that contains a carriage return without word changing that selection to highlighting the entire row in the table. In any other view mode I can highlight exactly whatever I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, this will only happen if you select using the mouse on the left margin (when the pointer reverses).

**Select over the text instead.**

Also, you may not know about the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ARROW</kbd> key combination.  This makes it easier to select passages as holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> skips **words** instead of characters.  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> will select to the end of the paragraph, then you can <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd> to get back to where you wanted.

**EDIT:**

`Tools` - > `Options` -> `Edit Tab` -> Uncheck **When Selecting, Automatically Select Entire Word**

**EDIT 2:**

So I did some more research.  Apparently this is a function of how outline view treats paragraphs.  In outline view, the engine **automatically** selects a larger section of text, and as a consequence when you select a portion of a cell with a CR in it, the engine interprets that to mean you want the whole row.

This is fixed **after** Office 2003, i.e. works fine in 2007.  There's not a fix for versions prior to 2007 besides not using outline view to edit tables.

Comment: That's all good in normal view. But still fails in outline mode. - see edit to OP.

Comment: OK, try disabling auto-select word.  See my edit.

Comment: @jnk: I had already done that. Still not fixed :-(

Comment: @Mick - is it an issue in all user profiles on the PC?  Try another one to see if it is persistent.

Comment: @jnk: am now at a different location - using different OS (XP) - problem is the same. See second edit to OP.

Comment: @Mick - It's an issue in the engine.  See the edit.  Basically, it's not fixable in that version of Office.

Comment: @jnk: that sounds like a definitive answer to me - thanks for that.

Comment: @mick - Happy to help, but sorry there's not a fix!